# formula/script to concatenate all probablities between two ranges with specified delimiter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So let's say I have 2 items in column A and 10 items in Column B. Is there a simple formula/script to output all the the probabilities of joining them?!

The output would be 2*10= 20 results

Thanks

EXAMPLE SCREENSHOT:
https://gmkr.io/s/59563cd5e76ce8393bee7c17/0

Comment: Does that mean that each probability would be 0.05 ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
=arrayformula(row(indirect("1:"&count(A:A)*count(B:B)))^0/(count(A:A)*count(B:B)))
```

Starting with two items in column A and ten in column B, this will give you a column containing 0.05 repeated 20 times. Replace count with counta if the items are not numeric.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I've edited my question to add a screenshot of what my desired result is..

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final answer:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($C$2)+1>COUNTA($A$2:$A$41)*COUNTA($B$2:$B$301),"",INDEX($A$2:$A$41,INT((ROW()-ROW($C$2))/COUNTA($B$2:$B$301)+1))&" "&INDEX($B$2:$B$301,MOD(ROW()-ROW($C$2),COUNTA($B$2:$B$301))+1))
```

[FINAL OUPUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jj9g.png)